# How can I check the expected intent sent without actually launching activity in Espresso?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I have a UI test which clicks a button, and then launch a new Activity in its onClickListener. The test checks whether expected intent is sent or not.

My problem is, I want to test whether expected intent is sent **without actually launching the activity**. Because I found that new activity initializes its state, and it makes subsequent tests flaky.

I know there are two [Espresso Intents](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/index.html) API, which are `intended` and `intending`, but both fail to meet my needs. `intended` API actually launches the target activity, and `intending` API doesn't launch the activity, but it calls `onActivityResult` callback which I don't want either. Because I'm afraid that code inside `onActivityResult` may cause another flakiness.

Also `intending` doesn't assert whether matching intent is sent. It just calls `onActivityResult` callback when matching intent is found, which means I have to check whether `onActivityResult` is called or not!

Is there a clean way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Espresso's `Intents` class is a concise and handy api, but when it doesn't meet your needs, there is an alternative. If you use `AndroidJUnit4` test runner, you can get `Instrumentaion` instance using `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation()`, and then you can add `Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor` instance.

```
Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor am = new Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor("YOUR_ACTIVITY", null, true);
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().addMonitor(am);
onView(withId(R.id.view_id_to_perform_clicking)).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(click());
assertTrue(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().checkMonitorHit(am, 1));
```

The third parameter of `ActivityMonitor` constructor tells we want to block activity launching. Note that this approach has its limitation. In contrast to Espresso Intents' [rich Matcher support](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/index.html#intent-matchers), You can not set multiple condition for `ActivityMonitor`.

You can find several samples in [ApiDemos](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/), especially in `ContactsSelectInstrumentation` class.

Comment: Is there a way to test the extras passed into the Intent with ActivityMonitor?

Answer (score 19):

If you want to test whether expected intent is sent without actually launching the activity you can do it by capturing the intent with an activityResult and then catching the activity :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
ActivityResult intentResult = new ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);

intending(anyIntent()).respondWith(intentResult);

onView(withId(R.id.view_id_to_perform_clicking)).check(matches(isDisplayed())).perform(click());

intended(allOf(hasComponent(ActivityToBeOpened.class.getName())));
```

This would catch any attempt of launching ActivityToBeOpened. If you want to be more specific you can also catch an intent with Extras:

```
intended(allOf(hasComponent(ActivityToBeOpened.class.getName()), hasExtra("paramName", "value")));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This solution is clean and keeps us within the Espresso-Intents patterns. Great for situations where we don't care if `onActivityResult()` is ever called. e.g. testing that a browser intent was launched

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can block any intent to launch an external or your own activity but still use the rich Espresso Intents API:

```
    Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor soloMonitor = solo.getActivityMonitor();
    instrumentation.removeMonitor(soloMonitor);
    IntentFilter filter = null;
    // Block any intent
    Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor monitor = instrumentation.addMonitor(filter, null, true);
    instrumentation.addMonitor(soloMonitor);

    // User action that results in an external browser activity being launched.
    user.clickOnView(system.getView(R.id.callButton));
    instrumentation.waitForIdleSync();

    Intents.intended(Matchers.allOf(
            IntentMatchers.hasAction(Matchers.equalTo(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)),
            IntentMatchers.hasData(Matchers.equalTo(Uri.parse(url))),
            IntentMatchers.toPackage(chromePackage)));

    instrumentation.removeMonitor(monitor);
```

You able to do that because Espresso Intents still records every Intent with [IntentMonitor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/intent/IntentMonitor.html) callback even if you block them. Look at the source code of [Espresso Intents](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/intents/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/intent/Intents.java) on how they do that.

If you use [Robotium Solo](https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium) framework you need to move your own `ActivityMonitor` before their one. Otherwise just skip the lines related to this.