# how to (check)know auto start permission allowed or not?

Tags: java, android

Hello I used this code for start Autostart permission in android mi,oppo,vivo device.this perfect running, but how to know autostart permission allowed by user.

```
private void addAutoStartup() {

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
        if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
        } else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
        } else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
        } else if ("Letv".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"));
        } else if ("Honor".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
        }

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("exc", String.valueOf(e));
    }
}
```

How to find out if this permission allowed or not?

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486537/how-to-check-expected-intent-sent-without-actually-launching-activity-in-espress) helps

Comment: Why do you flag something as Kotlin, that clearly is Java? It makes no sense to do that, just because it's android.

Comment: Have you solved this issue so far? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer you can't**

As of now it can be done via root but it is not recommended and can potentially harm user's device .
As for me i tend to create a dialog and redirect user to autostart screen.
If user click on "do not show again(checkbox)" simply stop showing that dialog but consider this as a liable option but bad practice

[Permission Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNkUI.png)